# Laravel How to easy filtering of Eloquent all?

Tags: laravel, filter

I have a Customer Model that it`s called like this:

```
$Customer = Customer::all();
```

How can I change if I have a filter request like "status"?

I tried this way:

```
$Customer = Customer::orderBy('id');
  if($filter->has('active')){
    $Customer->where('status',$filter->status);
  }
$Customer->count();
```

The problem is if I don`t set any filter I don't get all Customers. And I don't want to write another if. I want to change

```
$Customer = Customer::orderBy('id');
```

to get all and if filter is set I want only filter. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you get the [query()](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_query) method of the eloquent model, you obtain a query builder for that model, all what you have to do is add `wheres` and `orderby`... to that query builder then call `count()` to get the count:

```
 $customer = Customer::query()->orderBy('id');
        if($filter->has('active')){
            $customer= $customer->where('status',$filter->status);
        }
        $customerCount=$customer->count();
```